# Basic math formula confusion

Tags: math, equality, bit, redundancy

I was studying about redundancy bits and I came across this equation and table.
Now I am not sure how they get the "minimum number" redundancy bits column.

[image]

So how would they get maximum and minimum number of redundancy bits `r` require to correct `n` bits of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition: it's the smallest integer value of `r` that satisfies the stated equation, `2ʳ ≥ n + r + 1`.

I don't see anything about "maximum number of redundancy bits."

Comment: Now, if you're asking how to _solve_ that equation - not a question for SO.

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_minimum_number_of_redundant_bits_that_error-correcting_code_requires_for_data_units_that_are_5_bits_long have a look at this question, isnt the answer suppose to be 3 bits?

Comment: @AmberArroway `n=5` and `r=3` does not satisfy the inequality in the text, as it's not true that `8 >= 9`. So for `n=5` the "smallest integer such that" the inequality holds is `4`, as given both in the table and that link.

Comment: No, the answer is not supposed to be 3 bits. Fill in the equation for `r=3` and `n=5`. It is not satisfied for those values. `2³ ≥ 5 + 3 + 1` but `8` is not greater than or equal to `9`.

Comment: @AmberArroway for 10 bits, you need to solve this: `2ʳ - r ≥ 11`. By trial and error, it's easy to find that the smallest value of `r` that satisfies that equation is ... `4`.